# Gradle Project Structure

Tags: java, selenium, gradle, build.gradle

I am working on selenium Gradle project in which I accidentally changed some configuration that causes changes in build structure.  before change my project structure was

project-dir

- .gradle
- .idea
- **build**
- gradle
- out
- src

now its

project-dir

- .gradle
- .idea
- **classes**
- gradle
- out
- src

when I run command "gradlew build" it should run all the feature files but it is not working after change. can you help me what went wrong. I am new to all this.

I am using
gradle 4.12
selenium 2.53.0
cucumber-junit 1.2.5
cucumber-java 1.2.5
cucumber-core 1.2.5

Gradle.build file:

-

```
import java.text.DateFormat

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

task gitBuildId {

    description = "Determine the build id from git"
    def buildIdOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def errorsOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    def extraInfo = ""
    try {
        exec {
            // TODO: use a java git library?
            standardOutput = buildIdOut
            errorOutput = errorsOut
            commandLine 'git', 'log', '-1', '--pretty=format:%ct|%h', 'HEAD'
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        buildIdOut.write('0'.getBytes())
        if (errorsOut.toString().contains("Not a git repository")) {
            extraInfo = "(Not a git repository and/or no commits found)\n" +
                    "Type: git init; git add *; git commit *;"
        }
    }
    //OR? def buildIdOut = (long) ((new Date()).getTime() / 1000)
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"))

    //split into hash and timestamp
    String[] parts = buildIdOut.toString().split("\\|")
    def inTimeStamp = Long.parseLong(parts[0])
    def date = new Date((inTimeStamp as long) * 1000)
    def dateString = df.format(date)
    def buildId = "${dateString}.${parts[1]}"
    println "buildId = ${buildId} ${extraInfo}"
    ext.output = {
        return buildId
    }
}

if (JavaVersion.current().isJava8Compatible()) {
    allprojects {
        tasks.withType(Javadoc) {
            options.addStringOption('Xdoclint:none', '-quiet')
        }
    }
}

//def buildId = rootProject.tasks.gitBuildId.output()
def rpmVersion = '0.0.0'
//apply plugin: 'java'
//apply plugin: 'gradle-one-jar'
apply plugin: 'application'
//apply plugin: 'idea'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

// UTF-8 should be standard by now. So use it!
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

mainClassName = 'cucumber.api.cli.Main'

// Add Gradle OneJar Plugin, see https://github.com/rholder/gradle-one-jar
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '2.53.0'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '1.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-jvm-deps', version: '1.0.3'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'gherkin', version: '2.7.3'
    testCompile group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-all', version: '1.10.8'
    testCompile group: 'com.mashape.unirest', name: 'unirest-java', version: '1.4.9'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.3.6'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpasyncclient', version: '4.0.2'
    testCompile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.3.6'
    testCompile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20140107'



    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '5.1.6'
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '1.2.5'
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-jvm-deps', version: '1.0.3'
}

// Configure the oneJar task
task oneJar() {
    doLast {
        mainClass = mainClassName
    }
}

//def buildId = rootProject.tasks.gitBuildId.output()

allprojects {

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'signing'
    apply plugin: 'application'

    mainClassName = 'cucumber.api.cli.Main'

    // IDE support
    apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/ide.gradle')

    //cucumber support
    //apply from: rootProject.file('gradle/cucumber.gradle')

    if (version == 'unspecified') {
        version = '0.0.0'

        def envVersion = System.env['VERSION']
        if (envVersion) {
            version = envVersion
        }
    }

    distZip.doFirst {
        copy {
            from('bin') {
                include '**/*'
            }
            into file("src/dist/bin")
            fileMode = 0755
        }
    }
}

task deleteTestResults() {
    delete "build/test-results/test/"
    delete "cucumber-html-reports"
}


/*task cucumberTest() {

    def arglist = ["--monochrome", "--plugin", "pretty", "--glue", "com.automation.server",
                   "src/test/resources/features/"]

    return javaexec {
        main = "cucumber.api.cli.Main"
        classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
        args = arglist
    }
}*/

test {
    //we want display the following test events
    testLogging {
        events "PASSED", "STARTED", "FAILED", "SKIPPED"
        //showStandardStreams = true
    }
}

task testBoth {

    println 'This is executed last during the execution phase.'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.0'
}
artifacts {
    oneJar
}
```

Comment: Can you post your gradle build file please?

Comment: Why don't you simply revert your change?

Comment: I can't revert all changes. there are many commits and I don't know exactly when this happened

Comment: @EM-Creations  I have added my gradle.build file. can you tell whats possibly went wrong?

Comment: could you also add `gradle/ide.gradle` ? the `build.gradle` script does not seem to contain anything that could explain the project structure issue..

Comment: Ohk, but can you please tell me what are you looking for? because I haven't touched these files